# item won't append when it has a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, append

So I am trying to append a select, and it works fine when the class of this plugin, bootstrap-select, is not attached:

```
var select = $("<select class='new-select'></select>");
$('#selects-container').append(select);
```

However, when I add the class 'selectpicker', the select is appended, but it's not processed through the javascript of the plugin, and is therefore not visible.

```
var select = $("<select class='new-select selectpicker'></select>");
$('#selects-container').append(select);
```

So my question is how to get the new appended select to be ran through the javascript of the plugin and be formatted as would a select that was present on screen load.

Sincere thanks for the help, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have jsfiddle or plunker...

Answer (score 1):

So there are a number of ways to declare new DOM nodes using jQuery. For your task specifically, you'll want to specify an options object as the second argument, then add attributes to that, rather than in the selection string itself.

Try this:

```
var select = $('<select></select>', {
  'class': 'new-select selectpicker'
});
$('#selects-container').append(select);
```

Also, be aware of this, from [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery):

> The name "class" must be quoted in the object since it is a JavaScript
>   reserved word, and "className" cannot be used since it refers to the
>   DOM property, not the attribute.